# Show that $u$ attains its maximum over $\bar{D}$ on $\partial D$. (Karatzas and Shreve's book)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $D$ be a bounded, connected set in $R^d$ and $∂D$ its boundary.

- Suppose  $u$ is defined and continuous on $\bar{D}$, and $u$ is harmonic in $D$. Show that $u$ attains its maximum over $\bar{D}$ on $\partial D$.
- If $v$ is another function, harmonic in $D$ and continuous on $\bar{D}$, and $v=u$ on $\partial D$, then $v=u$ on $D$ as well.

For the second question : let $h=v-u$, by the first question $h$ attains its maximum over $\partial D$, or $h=0$ in $\partial D$, then by the maximum principle $h=0$ on $D$, i.e $u=v$ on $D$.

For the first one, I din't know what to do ! so any help is appreciated !

Source : Ex p.242 Brownian motion and stochastic calculus by Karatzas and Shreve.

Comment: The first one is simply a consequence of the Maximum Principle which K&S printed just a few lines before that Exercise 4.2.4. on p. 242.

Comment: Hi ! first of all sorry for my late answer. I didn't really can understand it because the theorem states that " that if $u$ is harmonic in the open, connected domain $D$ and $u$ achieves its supremum over $D$ at some point in $D$, then $u$ is identically constant", but here the question is to prove the existence of maximum !

Comment: Knowing that $u$ is continuous on the compact $\bar{D}$ we know that the maximum exists. If it achieves this maximum (which is at the same time the supremum) in $D$ (not on the boundary) then $u$ is constant. Then, very trivially, it achieves the maximum on the boundary as well.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I can see it now ! Can you please take a look to this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373015/unbounded-solutions-for-dirichlet-problem-with-stochastic-approach